# Set ImageView with selected Image from Camera or Gallery

Tags: android, image, android-camera

In my Activity I want put in a ImageView a photo from camera or gallery!
From camera this code work well, while when I take an image from gallery it works until when I choose my photo! After, it don't give me it in imageview! Who can help me?

Here is it **MainActivity** code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mTakePhoto;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);


        final String[] option = new String[] { "Take from Camera", "Select from Gallery" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Option");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Selected Item", String.valueOf(which));
                if (which == 0) {
                    callCamera();
                }
                if (which == 1) {
                    callGallery();
                }

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        mTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_REQUEST:

            setPic();

            break;
        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:

            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();

            if (extras2 != null) {
                Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                // convert bitmap to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
                // Inserting Contacts
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume: " + this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    File photoFile = null;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/uploads";
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();

        File image = new File(storageDir + "/" + imageFileName + ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.i(TAG, "photo path = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor << 1;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postRotate(90);
        // Rotating Bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);

    }

    public void callCamera() {

        dispatchTakePictureIntent();

    }

    public void callGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

    }
}
```

Thanks,Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have this code in your camera :

```
 mImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
```

But you dont have it on the gallery. You should set the bitmap too in `case PICK_FROM_GALLERY` on your `onActivityResult`.

The code should be like this :

```
if (extras2 != null)
{
   Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
   //your other code
   mImageView.setImageBitmap(yourImage);
}
```

Comment: in my
case PICK_FROM_GALLERY: i tryed to put setPic(); but it give me back java.lang.nullPointerException. Of Course i need setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP), you are right but whats the better way? Any suggestion? Thanks